# Not able to register and unregister .dll file through electron-builder custom NSIS include script

Tags: node.js, electron, windows-installer, nsis, electron-builder

I have created a [electron](https://www.electronjs.org) desktop app and created a installer using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/).

Now I want to add capability of `registering` a `.dll` file at the time of `installation` of my desktop app and `unregistering` it at the time of `uninstallation`.

My `installer.nsh` file is

```
!macro customInstall
  Exec "regsvr32.exe $INSTDIR\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\obs-studio-node\obs-virtualsource.dll"
!macroend

!macro customUnInstall
  Exec "regsvr32.exe /u $INSTDIR\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\obs-studio-node\obs-virtualsource.dll"
!macroend
```

My `electron-builder` config is

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "include": "installer.nsh"
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icon.png"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icon.png"
    }
  }
```

But this is not working for me. I have tried both `Exec` and `ExecWait` none is working.
What I am missing to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the installer as admin?
Registering the .dll requires administrator rights.

Set admin rights in your script first with:

**RequestExecutionLevel admin**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below options,

```
!macro customInstall
Exec "regsvr32.exe 
$INSTDIR\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\obs-studio-node\obs-virtualsource.dll"
!macroend

!macro customUnInit
Exec "regsvr32.exe /u 
$INSTDIR\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\obs-studio-node\obs-virtualsource.dll"
!macroend
```